# An e in "absured"?

Tags: meaning, orthography

A few paragraphs in to Chapter 3 of "How to win friends and influence people"—a book that I'm embarrassed to admit I've undertaken—I found what just appears to be an odd spelling for "absurd."  Unfortunately, its not clear from the context that "absurd" is the intended word:

"Why talk about what we want? That is childish. Absured. (...)"

If the word "absurd" was intended, it certainly seems out of place.  So my question: Is this an obsolete spelling for absured? A typo? Another word entirely?

EDIT: Perhaps a homely spelling for rustic effect?

Comment: OED gives three variants: 15–16 absurde, 15– absurd, 16 obsurd.

Comment: It's just a tupo.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a typo in your edition (see for instance page 32 of this [Google Books link](http://books.google.be/books?id=0dJDdw39UDMC&pg=PR9&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=3#v=onepage&q=absurd&f=false)).

By the way the adjective *absurd* comes from the Latin word [*absurdus*](http://etymonline.com/?search=absurd), so it seems improbable that an older spelling would have an extra *e*.

Edit:
I've also found the version with an extra *e*:

[image]

Because these two versions exist, I can think of two explanations: either this is a subtle joke/play on words (referring to the childish or absurd variant), or it is just a plain typo. I'm inclined to think it is the latter.

Comment: I'm not completely convinced.  I can't see the book from your link, but both amazon and google in the US show the same spelling.  The book is in its 4th edition, so it seems unlikely that its a typo that somehow made it past the first 3 editions.

Comment: I could see the book from the link, after clicking on one of the sections initially displayed - but I found it on page *numbered* **32**. Is it not possible that the typo was *introduced* in a later edition? Are you reading a hard copy or e-copy?

Comment: A screenshot from my link: http://i41.tinypic.com/344fguc.jpg

Comment: @TrevorD: I'm reading an e-copy. The more I think about it, the more I'm leaning towards an interpretation as a (rather poor) joke.  But the word absurd still doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: It's a typo. Typos persist. Even in frequently-read books. And that's not a joke that Norman Vincent Peale would ever, ever make.

Comment: Er, but what about the author, Dale Carnegie? Mightn't he make such a joke?

Comment: The number of typos in e-books is absurdly high. As far as I can tell, it is still optical character recognition software that reads the original to create the e-book. Lots of dumb errors, and no effort to correct them.

Comment: @BobbiBennett Is that absurdly high or absuredly high :-)